# sorted dictionary with lambda / Python3 vs Python 2

Tags: python

I want to sort dictionary keys by values using sorted function with lambda function

```
word_count = {"a":25, "and":10, "the":15,"for":9, "or":7}
```

using this sorted function:

```
x = sorted(word_count.items(), key=lambda(k,v):v, reverse=True)
```

This function works in Python 2.7, but in Python 3 I'm getting Syntax error.

Could you pls someone explain why this sorting function doesnt work in Python3? Thx.

Comment: `sorted(word_count.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`

Comment: thx, but this is different syntax, i wanted explanation why my solution doesnt work in Python3 but works in Python2

Comment: Ok, I found that tuple paramater unpacking was removed in Python3,  that was the reason why my solution didnt work in Python3 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/